# Importing sql server 2017 database to neo4j

Tags: neo4j

i am trying to search for a way to import database from sql server to neo4j. I searched for a way if exist but i didn't find what i want. My case is : database contains many tables so i want to bring them to neo4j in one click ( if exist ) using a tools or writing dotnet program

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'one-click' solution - but you said you're happy to write some code, so -- here we go!

Neo4j can import via JDBC, via a set of procedures called APOC (https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_load_jdbc). To do this, you'll need the SQL Server JDBC driver (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

And here (https://tbgraph.wordpress.com/2017/07/24/neo4j-apoc-load-jdbc/) is a blog describing the process, so that should get you all up and running!